# How to structure an Entity in Spring boot/ JPA having multiple foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I hava a table "Details" which has information from "City", "Town", "branch" tables. They all are one time configuration tables and their information is constant.They never need to be updated.

"Details" table have foreign keys references from these tables like "city_id","town_id","branch_id".

Now the problem is, when the data uploads for "details", it has "City_name","town_name" and "branch name".I need to convert this data in Ids to store them in "details"

What should I do to achieve my objective?

Example:

```
 Data uploads: "City name","town name", "branch name".
```

City:

```
id  | City_name
 1  | city name
 2  | city name 2
```

Town:

```
id  | Town_name
 1  | town name
 2  | town name 2
```

Branch

```
id  | branch_name
 1  | branch name
 2  | branch name 2
```

Now, data that must be stored in "details"

```
details_id | city_id | town_id | branch_id
 1         |1        |1        |1
```

Comment: Is it a form submission from UI? If yes, how the UI list is being populated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fetch referred objects and then create the entity and save it. Should be something like:

```
City foundCity = CityRepository.findByName(cityName).orElseThrow(() -> new EnityNotFoundException("City not found"));
...
Detail detail = new Detail();
detail.setCity(foundCity);
...
detailRepository.save(detail);
```

If you have big number of `Details` to create and the number of referred objects are not so huge, you might need to load all referred objects into memory before proceeding. Like

```
List<City> cities = cityRepository.findAll();
...

List<Detail> detailsToSave = new ArrayList<>();

City foundCity = cities.stream()
        .filter(item -> name.equals(item.getName()))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new EnityNotFoundException("City not found"));
    ...
    Detail detail = new Detail();
    detail.setCity(foundCity);
    ...
    detailsToSave.add(detail);
    ....

 detailRepository.saveAll(detailsToSave);
```

Comment: thank you for the response but I have millions of records being uploaded in "detail" from a file. For upload i am just using DTO to copy data between file and Entity, mapping fields between them using BeanUtils.copyProperties. 

would you please assist me how your solution will work in this scenario?

Comment: If the number of master object records are not huge, it is better to load all records into memory before proceeding.

Comment: I have update the answer to include the scenario of big number of records to proceed.